# Bad request/Invalid host name from IHS in Connections 6.5 Component Pack search API call (OrientMe)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, ibm-connections, ibmhttpserver

After [installing](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_install_upgrade_intro.html) and [configuring](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_config_intro.html) HCL Component Pack 6.5, I navigated to `https://<cnx-ihs-host>/social/home` and saw parts of OrientMe with some errors:

[image]

The browser console shows multiple http 500 errors, for example `https://cnx-ihs-host/community_suggestions/api/recommend/communities?count=30`

```
{"errorMessage":"Bad XML response from Search Application: Error: Unexpected close tag\nLine: 11\nColumn: 7\nChar: >","error":"Error: Error: Unexpected close tag\nLine: 11\nColumn: 7\nChar: >\n    at getCommunitiesFromAtom (/home/ibm/app/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js:98:11)\n    at Request.request [as _callback] (/home/ibm/app/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js:163:19)\n    at Request.self.callback (/home/ibm/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ibm/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ibm/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)\n    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)"}
```

So I increment the IHS log to debug and found the following entry:

```
[debug] mod_proxy_http.c(63): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //cnx-ihs-host/community_suggestions/api/recommend/communities
...
[debug] vhost.c(791): [client 1.2.3.4:44004] [strict] Invalid host name 'cnx65.ihs-host, cnx65.ihs-host', problem near: , cnx6
[debug] vhost.c(886): [client 172.19.34.4:44004] Client sent malformed Host header: cnx65-test-daniel.k8s02.company.internal, cnx65.ihs-host
```

For me this seems that the hostname was set multiple times like this:

```
Host: cnx65.ihs-host, cnx65.ihs-host
```

### Why does this happend and how could it be fixed?

#### Analysis on k8s component pack

I searched for the source, which seems the `community-suggestions` deployment. For easier troubleshooting (just have to watch 1 pod instead of 3), the deployment was downgraded from 3 to 1 replicas:

```
kubectl scale deploy community-suggestions --replicas=1
```

Now there is just a single pod. To get more detailled output, I found the env variable `LOG_LEVEL` which was stick to `info`. So I used `kubectl edit deploy community-suggestions` to set it to debug. This gave me much more infos:

```
{"pid":23,"hostname":"community-suggestions-bdc8c6577-cxz5x","name":"community-suggestions/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js","level":30,"time":1583489495149,"msg":"Fetching Community Details using Blue API: https://cnx-ihs-host/search/atom/mysearch?returnType=json&constraint={'type':'field','id':'id','values':[\"ac16d726-118c-4876-a1fd-7f0574aa4cf3\",\"COMMUNITIES\"],'exactMatch':true}&scope=communities:entry","v":1}
2020-03-06T10:11:35.149Z - debug: [orient-web-client] ENTRY: RequestAuthUtils.sanitizeHeaders undefined
2020-03-06T10:11:35.149Z - debug: [orient-web-client] EXIT: RequestAuthUtils.sanitizeHeaders undefined
{"pid":23,"hostname":"community-suggestions-bdc8c6577-cxz5x","name":"community-suggestions/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js","level":20,"time":1583489495180,"msg":">> getCommunitiesFromAtom <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n<p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request\nerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>IBM_HTTP_Server at cnx65.internal Port 443</address>\n</body></html> a","v":1}
{"pid":23,"hostname":"community-suggestions-bdc8c6577-cxz5x","name":"community-suggestions/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js","level":50,"time":1583489495180,"msg":"Error while calling resolve on getCommunitiesFromAtom {}","v":1}
{"pid":23,"hostname":"community-suggestions-bdc8c6577-cxz5x","name":"community-suggestions/lib/server/boot/root.js","level":50,"time":1583489495181,"msg":"Bad XML response from Search Application: Error: Error: Unexpected close tag\nLine: 11\nColumn: 7\nChar: >","v":1}
```

It shows that the problem is an API request to the search `/search/atom/...`. Opening those link in the browser with the same CNX user specified in component pack, I get a valid XML file without any error messages.

The mentioned `/home/ibm/app/lib/server/suggestedCommunitiesService.js` file from the exception generates it's target API address using this function:

```
function getSearchRoute(res, ids) {
  const restEndPoint = `/atom/mysearch?returnType=json&constraint={'type':'field','id':'id','values':${JSON.stringify(ids)},'exactMatch':true}&scope=communities:entry`;
  const connectionsSearchUrl = `${process.env.CONNECTIONS_SEARCH_URL}`;
  return connectionsSearchUrl + getAuthSchemeFragment(res.locals.isOauth) + restEndPoint;
}
```

Inside the pod, env variable `CONNECTIONS_SEARCH_URL` points correctly to `https://cnx-ihs-host/search`. Component Pack uses the `request` nodejs module to set a normal GET request:

```
request({
  method: 'GET',
  headers: scHeaders,
  uri,
  jar
}, ...
```

I see no reason why there should be an issue with the host header caused by this code.

Answer (score 0):

Is customizer deployed? Missing header could be customizer related.

Check nginx forwarding rules, check configmap (http and https).

Comment: Currently no customizer deployed. Just a default kubernetes ingress that forwards to the IHS directly, but this should forward all headers I assume?

Answer (score 0):

I had an ingress in front of IHS, which should act as router to IHS or the K8s part (having an reverse proxy is recommendede from the docs):

```
User <-----> Ingress <-----> IHS
```

Later, this proxy should also be used for k8s, so that it decides wherever to route to IHS (WebSphere backend) or the Component Pack (e.g. OrientMe).

The problem was that `x-forwarded-host` was set to `cnx65.ihs-host, cnx65.ihs-host` in combination with the [default behavior of k8s ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2463), which set `x-forwarded-for` headers as `Host`. I'm currently figuring out why those headers contains the hostname twice. But the main issue was the k8s ingress behavior, which results in `Host: cnx65.ihs-host, cnx65.ihs-host` being passed to IHS.

It seems not possible to fix this out of the box, but by adding a custom snippet in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` that sets the host header to the real http host:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-service
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"

    # https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2463#issuecomment-423230548
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_clear_input_headers "Host" "X-Forwarded-Host";
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_x_forwarded_host;
```